# Why does this Java program claim 2 != 2 with nested ifs?

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean-logic, nested

Let's see this simple Java code:

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (1 == 1)
            if (2 == 2)
                if (2 != 2) // <-- should end here and do nothing
                    System.out.println("2 != 2");
            else
                System.out.println("2 != 2");
        else
            System.out.println("1 != 1");
    }
}
```

As the comment says, it should see `1==1`, then `2==2`, but then the most nested condition `2!=2` fails, so the program quits without printing anything. But that is not the case, instead it says `2!=2`:

```
$ javac A.java && java A
2 != 2
```

Why?

Curiously, it works as expected  in Python:

```
>>> if (1 == 1):
...     if (2 == 2):
...         if (2 != 2):
...             print("2 != 2");
...     else:
...         print("2 != 2");
... else:
...     print("1 != 1");
... 
>>>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With correct indentation (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> in Eclipse) you see why your result seems to be `2 != 2`:

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (1 == 1) // true
            if (2 == 2) // true
                if (2 != 2) // false
                    System.out.println("2 != 2");
                else
                    System.out.println("2 != 2"); // is actually 2 == 2, gets executed
            else
                System.out.println("1 != 1"); // is actually 2 != 2
    }
}
```

You probably have a Python background where spaces matter. In Java they don't matter and can be placed without having an effect on execution. If you write `if` statments like this, Java will nest them internally and not by indentation (just like HTML tags - last if, first else and so on).

To prevent this you should (always) use braces in Java and make use of auto formatting (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> in Eclipse as mentioned above). This helps with readability. BTW: If you don't use braces in Java, only the following line is affected by the `if`. You would then have to add braces every time you need to execute more than one statement. So braces also improve extensibility, because you can always add statements and don't have to add them later.

Answer (score 9):

Just indent your code and **add braces** to it:

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (1 == 1) {
            if (2 == 2) {
                if (2 != 2) {
                    System.out.println("2 != 2");
                } else {
                    //comes here
                    System.out.println("2 != 2");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("1 != 1");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is why when coding in Java is highly recommended that you use braces even when you have a one line `if` or `for` sentence.

Answer (score 5):

You have a dangling else problem in the Java code.

In Java, indentation does not affect which `if` statement the `else` joins with. It's always the nearest.

You can solve this by using braces around the bodies of the if and else statements. You can avoid this problem by always using braces around the bodies of `if` statements.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (1 == 1) {
        if (2 == 2) {
            if (2 != 2) // <-- should end here and do nothing
                System.out.println("2 != 2");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("2 != 2");
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("1 != 1");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java always use braces, unlike Python indentation doesn't matter except for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly in java else matches to the nearest if as told by other posters here. But if you had any other statement before else there as follows :

```
        if (1 == 1)
            if (2 == 2)
                if (2 != 2) // <-- should end here and do nothing
                    System.out.println("2 != 2");
        System.out.println("out of inner if loop !");
        else
            System.out.println("2 != 2");
            else
                System.out.println("1 != 1");
```

then youe system.out statement is at the same level as the outermost if statement and you will get the error to else statement because java can't match else to any if's. Thats why braces are so necessary in java.